# Currency abbreviation (EUR, USD, GBP) convert to currency symbol (€, $, £)

Tags: c#, asp.net, currency, symbols

I have some dropdownbox with currency abbreviations like EUR, USD, GBP and for all the other currencies. I would like to use some c# .Net functionality/method where I can insert an currency abbreviation and it returns the currency symbol (€, $, £).

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 4):

You can run through all cultures till you find a match:

```
public string GetCurrencySymbolFromAbbreviation(string abbreviation)
{
    foreach (CultureInfo nfo in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
    {
        RegionInfo region = new RegionInfo(nfo.LCID);
        if (region.ISOCurrencySymbol == abbreviation)
        {
            return region.CurrencySymbol;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing in the framework to handle this specifically, but you could solve it using a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) of currency abbreviations and symbols.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of anything built into the framework, but if you've got a list of the currencies you're interested in, this sounds like a perfect place to use a `Dictionary<string, string>` or *possibly* a `Dictionary<string, char>` (I don't know if there are any multi-character symbols, but I wouldn't be surprised).

Comment: The old Deutsch Mark symbol was DM, so I bet there are some others out there.

Comment: `KWD`, `SAR`, `AED` are some three letter currency acronyms. The majority of currencies don't have a symbol but use their ISO abbreviations listed in [ISO 4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217). If you app is localized, you should use the appropriate symbol. For example `Kuwaiti Dinar` is `KWD` and also `د.ك`

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for some dynamic solution and I found this:

```
RegionInfo regionInfo = (from culture in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.InstalledWin32Cultures)
                                     where culture.Name.Length > 0
                                     let region = new RegionInfo(culture.LCID)
                                     where String.Equals(region.ISOCurrencySymbol, "EUR", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                                     select region).First();

string currencySymbol = regionInfo.CurrencySymbol;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an arraylist/ hashtable to store **EUR, USD, GBP** with their respective unicode **0x20A0**[EUR], **0x0024** [USD]& **0x00A3** [GBP].

You can fetch data from this arraylist/ hashtable when you require or onChange event of dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is, you Can use Database with Currency Name, Currency Symbol.
When you will select Currency Name it will automatic select the Currency Symbol and you can use that one.